# ambigious behaviour of increment operator in printf

Tags: c, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

the output of the programme

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

 int i = 10;
 printf("%d %d %d\n", ++i, i++, ++i);

}
```

is 13 11 13. Can someone please explain this ?

Comment: Undefined Behavior cannot be explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the oldest question ever. Why do people find this so fascinating?

This is undefined behavior; you're relying on side-effects without a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between modifications.